# How to overlay contours which share violently different ranges using corner.py

Tags: python, plot, overlay, contour

I want to overlay six contours in one figure using `fig=fig` in corner.py.

Four of the contours share similar scales and ranges. Thus they can be overlayed smoothly with the same parameter ranges.

But the ranges and scales of the last two contours are different violently from the former four contours. These two contours can be overlayed smoothly.

When overlaying the last two contours with the former four contours with the ranges setting as the ranges of the former four contours. It turned out to be an error. The error details are as follows:

````
  return ax.set_ylim(new_ylim)
Miniconda3-install\lib\site-packages\corner\core.py:583: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  sm /= sm[-1]
WARNING:root:Too few points to create valid contours ```
````